# Statistics on Answer speeds

Tags: support

Is it possible to collect statistics on how quickly questions are answered? Without collecting piles of answers back and processing them locally? In an Elastic Search instance you'd do this with the aggregations functionality.

I've read over the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs), though I haven't studied all of it in detail and could be missing something obvious.

Comment: You could probably do something in SEDE

Comment: Presumably you can take this [very rough bare bones SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1340368/average-time-to-answer) I just knocked up and go from there,

Comment: Probably of use: https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/790508 if you can get your head around the data form or manipulate it further

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) is an excellent resource for this type of analysis.

First, let's have a look at all questions answered within an hour:

[image]
([source](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1340706/time-to-first-answer-v1#graph))

The value for 0 minutes is a bit skewed because of self-answers. Otherwise, it looks like a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution); most questions are answered within about 10 minutes.

Here is an overview for two days:

[image]
([source](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1340707/time-to-first-answer-v2#graph))

You see that the vast majority of the (answered) questions is answered within the first two hours after posting. (To compare: [about 6.5k questions are unanswered](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+answers%3A0) – they don't appear in these graphs.)

Comment: 'merged questions can have older answers' your query comment cleared up some confusion for me. Thanks this is excellent.

Comment: You're welcome. [This](https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/1340719#graph) is what happens if you leave that out. I'm actually surprised that I thought of this *while* writing the first version of the query, not afterwards. Especially considering that it's Friday evening here 